# How can I write a search algorithm that searches through all user attributes in JavaScript with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

I have been working on an application to search through all the users in our organization, I have been using Angular to fetch all the users in an HTML table, right now I am working on a JavaScript search algorithm to search through all the attributes of a user like Username, Email.

```
  <h1>PKEYE - Auth0 list users</h1>
  <b>Search for the User: 
  
  </b>
  
     
        <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
           The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
        <!-- Username Column -->
        
            Username 
           {{ element?.username }}
        
        <!-- User ID Column -->
        
            User ID 
           {{ element?.user_id }}
        
        <!-- Email Column -->
        
            Email 
           {{ element?.email }}
        
        <!-- Identities Column -->
        
            Identities 
           {{ element?.identities[0]?.connection }}
        
        <!-- Actions Column -->
        
            Actions 
           
              Disable
           
        
        <!-- Header and Row Definitions -->
        
        
     
  
  
     function myFunction() {
       // Declare variables
       var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
       input = document.getElementById("gfg");
       filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
       table = document.getElementById("geeks");
       tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

       // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
       for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
         td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
         if (td) {
           txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
           if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
             tr[i].style.display = "";
           } else {
             tr[i].style.display = "none";
           }
         }
       }
     }        
           
  </script>
  <div>
     <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="page" name="page" min="0" max="15">
     <button (click)="getUsers()">Get Users</button>
  </div>
  <div class="paginator">
     <button [disabled]="page === 0" (click)="prevPage()">Previous</button>
     <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="page" name="page" min="0" max="15">
     <button (click)="getUsers()">Get Users</button>
  </div>
  <div class="paginator">
     <button [disabled]="page === 0" (click)="prevPage()">Previous</button>
     <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="page" name="page" min="0" max="15">
     <button [disabled]="page >= pageCount - 1" (click)="nextPage()">Next</button>
  </div>
```

I am not sure what is going wrong, could you help me out thanks.

I was trying to write a search algorithm that would search through all the user and it's attribute, I even tried using jQuery but none of it worked. I am fine with using JavaScript or any other methods as long as it search through the all the attributes in real-time.

Comment: In angular you needn't do it. You can have two arrays: allUsers and filteredUsers and use [*ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) to iterate over the array to create the table. The only you need is filter the allUsers arrays.